# How to copy one file to a folder and all its subfolders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

How do I copy one file to a folder and all its subfolders in Windows 7?

For example:

```
file.txt
```

will be copied to

```
folder/file.txt
folder/sub1/file.txt
folder/sub2/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This example, the directory c:\prc\a\fa has a file called file1,  and subdirectories a,b,c,d

The line that says for /f .........  will do it if you remove the word echo

```
C:\prc\a\fa>dir /b/s/ad <ENTER>
C:\prc\a\fa\a
C:\prc\a\fa\b
C:\prc\a\fa\c
C:\prc\a\fa\d

C:\prc\a\fa>for /F %f in ('dir /b/s/ad') do echo copy file1 %f <ENTER>

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\a
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\a

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\b
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\b

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\c
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\c

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\d
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\d

C:\prc\a\fa>
```

This FOR would also do it

```
C:\prc\a\fa>for /r %f in (.) do echo copy file1 %f
```

just remove the echo

there may be a better way than putting . in there but it works fine

```
C:\prc\a\fa>for /r %f in (.) do echo copy file1 %f <ENTER>

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\.
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\.

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\a\.
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\a\.

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\b\.
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\b\.

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\c\.
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\c\.

C:\prc\a\fa>echo copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\d\.
copy file1 C:\prc\a\fa\d\.

C:\prc\a\fa>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite any files already present in these subfolders?

Comment: it's just copying a single file, into each, so the only question of whether it overwrites or not, is if any folder has a file of that name in it, will that file be overwritten.  In this case you get a prompt, if it exists. if you did copy /Y it would do YES automatically, thus overwriting it.  To do No automatically is more tricky..  a workaround could be you could make the copy conditional on the file not existing at the destination, so after the do in the for, you'd do if not exist %f\file1 copy file1 %f

Comment: I see. I would have thought that if you had a file ```c:\prc\a\fa\d\file2.txt``` then the for loop ```%f``` would return ```c:\prc\a\fa\d\file2.txt```, so the copy command would be ```copy file1 c:\prc\a\fa\d\file2.txt```, which would overwrite the file.

Comment: @paul no 'cos there's no index going 1..9  like file%f.txt copying file[1 to 9].txt   and there's no *.*(star dot star) that just copies everything from source to dest. It's just a sequence of copy commands, where the source is statically file1, and the dest is one subdir after another. Try executing a FOR loop removing everything after the Do, and just saying  1  and try just saying  %f.    Normally a for loop loops through what's in the brackets for %f in (a b c) do echo %f  . but when you do /r it's like it generates what's in the brackets that is iterated through, that is, subdirectories.

Comment: Ah of course, you are limiting the ```for``` to look for '.' which can only be folders.  Cheers.

Comment: @Paul actually the '.' there doesn't do that, it's a weird thing. The /R has the special effect of making it go through subdirectories, try sticking an -a- in the brackets and it still go through subdirectories. try a *.  I was getting troubled by the FOR 'cos it wasn't going through empty subdirectories, but  it did if I stuck an 'a' in there(though appends an 'a' after each dir). so I stuck a dot in there and it still showed empties. If you test it you see it. I just realised though, I could've done /D or /D /R, with a * in it, 'cos with those it includes empties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1518/discussion-between-barlop-and-paul)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following PowerShell script:

```
dir -Recurse -Directory|
    foreach { copy \Path\To\File.txt $_.FullName }
```

Save above in to copy1tomany.ps1 file. Press Ctrl+Win and type powershell to get the Powershell prompt. Navigate to folder and type copy1tomany.ps1.